# DisplayPort vs Mini DisplayPort

Tags: displayport, mini-displayport

Is DisplayPort identical to Mini DisplayPort in everything except physical configuration? Same capacity/bandwidth/etc?

Is there ANY advantage to using one over the other beside the physical size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same. You can even use a passive adaptor to go from one to another.

The only advantage seems to be size. The regular plug is larger, easier to handle and looks less fragile.